# Como usar sistema responsivo do Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Gostaria de saber como utilizo somente a parte de design responsivo do Bootstrap e se possível me dar umas dicas de como aplicar no código HTML.

Comment: Aqui você pode encontrar e solucionar suas dúvidas de como iniciar o uso do bootrstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: o que exatamente você quer usar do Bootstrap: Grid, imagens, algum componente, somente as classes de visibilidade?

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente você adiciona uma classe ao seu elemento html.

Para os grids a estrutura da classe é:

```
.col-tamanhoDaTela-EspaçoASerOcupado

.col-sm-1 /*ocupa 1 espaço em telas pequenas*/
```

O grid do bootstrap se baseia em 12 espaços, então se você dar a classe `.col-sm-6` pra um elemento, ele vai ocupar metade da linha em uma resolução pequena.

As duas letras do meio representam o tamanho da tela, na [tabela da documentação](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) você pode ver melhor, mas simplificando:

**xs = extra small = muito pequena/celular.**

**sm = small = pequena/tablet.**

**md = medium = média/notebooks e pcs com telas menores.**

**lg = large = grande/notebooks e pcs com telas grandes.**

Você também pode utilizar classes que definem se o elemento é visível ou não e qual seu comportamento.

Ex.:

```
.visible-sm-block /* vai ser visível como um elemento tipo bloco em telas pequenas */
```

A estrutura é:

```
.visivelOuEscondido-TamanhoDaTela-Comportamento
```

Sendo que a parte do comportamento é opcional.

Na documentação tem duas tabelas bem bacanas:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options