# Ícones em tamanhos diferentes com Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-font-face

Olá, estou estudando o Bootstrap montando um site *OpenCart* onde o *layout* tem ícones padrões.

Fiz um módulo HTML para informações com 3 ícones usando Bootstrap,  mas eles seguem o padrão de tamanho do site (CSS):

```
.fa {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Quero que este ícones tenham tamanho diferenciado, ficando maiores. Não funciona mesmo usando `fa-3x`. Veja um exemplo aplicado abaixo.

Como faço isto?

```
"i class="fa fa-truck fa-3x pull-left fa-border"
```

Comment: Está importando o [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/) no seu código? - [Fiddle de exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/pvL9o4sp/)

Comment: Estes ícones que vc está usando são do font awesome, os do bootstrap vc chama com `glyphicon`, e dá pra mudar o tamanho com `<span style="fontsize: 18px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" id="outrasv">"</i></span>` p.ex. ou pela CSS usando classes etc.

Answer (score 6):

Como disse no comentário, estes ícones que vc está utilizando não são do Bootstrap, e sim do [fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/).

Veja [aqui](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-glyphs) os ícones do Bootstrap.

Esta é a forma básica de usar os ícones do Bootstrap:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-nomedoglyphicon"></i>
```

Exemplo:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i>
```

Para alterar o tamanho globalmente, utilizando CSS, faça assim:

```
i.glyphicon {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

Ou utilizando classes:

```
i.glyphicon.minhaclasse {
    font-size: 6em;
}
```

Criei um [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/yabs8doj/) pra demonstrar.

Também é possível alterar o tamanho utilizando `span`, como disse no comentário:

```
<span style="fontsize: 18px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i></span>
```

No [fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) (que tem muito mais ícones que o bootstrap, mas vc acabará utilizando duas bibliotecas), é basicamente a mesma coisa, com a diferença de que ele já vem com 5 tamanhos pré-definidos: `fa`-`fa-5x`. Exemplo:

```
<i class="fa fa-list-alt fa-2x"> Texto vinculado</i>
```

Não dá certo colocar o `style="font-size: 40px"` dentro da tag `<i>`, mas se vc colocar um tamanho como `span` e ainda o `fa-2x`, ele dobrará o tamanho determinado pelo `span`.

No código abaixo, o ícone terá tamanho equivalente a 80px:

```
 <span style="font-size: 40px"><i class="fa fa-list-alt fa-2x"></i></span>
```

Por fim, como disse o @re22, não se esqueça de importar a biblioteca do FA se for utilizá-lo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Ou faça [o download](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/), e importe localmente.

(Editei a resposta de novo pra incluir  a sugestão de como usar CSS pra alterar o tamanho, porque agora com a [ajuda desta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18478451/4734177) funcionou (mas não use span se estiver com o Bootstrap 3.0, use `<i>`, veja acima o fiddle)).

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação. Vou aplicar no projeto e aprendendo a usar melhor o Bootstrap.

Comment: @OmarAlmeida [nesta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59873/o-que-%c3%a9-e-como-funciona-o-bootstrap) tem várias respostas que podem ajudar no começo com o Bootstrap.